# Adding a secondary axis to the right

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I wanted to a plot a combo chart using GOOGLE CHARTS where my Sales are on the left y-axis and Salary is on the right y-axis(Secondary axis) as Line chart.
However, my code is not running. Not able to figure out where the problem is.
Please help.
Snippet of the code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function drawVisualization() {
    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Employee ID', 'Sales', 'Salary'],
      ['7000234', 560024, 9765],
      ['7000260', 1180800, 15621],
      ['7000262', 244308, 9212],
      ['7000273', 390912, 8650],
      ['7000288', 870445, 6692]
    ]);

    // Create and draw the visualization.
    var ac = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    ac.draw(data, {
      title : 'Sales and Salary',
      width: 800,
      height: 400,
      hAxis: {title: "Employee ID"},
      vAxes: [ 0: {title: "Sales"}, 1: {title:"Salary"}],
      series: {
              0:{ type: "bars", targetAxisIndex: 0 },
              1: { type: "line", targetAxisIndex: 1}
          },
    });
  }


  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the only error is in option `vAxes`. `{...}` should be used instead of `[...]`. You have to change:

```
vAxes: [ 0: {title: "Sales"}, 1: {title:"Salary"}],
```

to

```
vAxes: { 0: {title: "Sales"}, 1: {title:"Salary"}},
```

See [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/UpaCOHOy/1/edit)